# Return a different Content-Type Reponse on error

Tags: django-rest-framework

Given an endpoint with one renderer:

```py
class PNGRenderer(BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'image/png'
    format = 'png'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data

@renderer_classes((PNGRenderer, ))
def some_endpoint(request, format=None):
    filename = 'foo.png'
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        raise NotFound("File not found")
    else:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
            return response(data)
```

I would like to return `application/json` in case `foo.png` is not found. In real life `filename` not constantly `"foo.png"` but dynamic, obviously.

How can I return json such that `Content-Type` is properly set to `application/json` in the response even though format='png' was provided to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

While writing the question, I found the answer for changing the renderer: `request.accepted_renderer = JSONRenderer()`.

In particular:

```py
@renderer_classes((PNGRenderer, ))
def some_endpoint(request, format=None):
    filename = 'foo.png'
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        request.accepted_renderer = JSONRenderer()
        raise NotFound("File not found")
    else:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()
            return response(data)
```

I am not sure if this a a proper way to deal with exceptions for *binary* `Content-Type`'s.